# Почему пропадают данные в памяти при инициализации переменной?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ram

Всем привет.
Я начинающий разработчик, поэтому попытаюсь объяснить ситуацию как смогу.
Стек: С#, .NET 4.5, Visual Studio 2017.

При разработке приложения столкнулся с такой проблемой. При инициализации переменной в виде целочисленного массива:

```
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 4, 5, 7 };
```

На некоторых компьютерах (2 из 10), у программы в этой переменной, после инициализации, хранятся совершенно другие числа в последовательности. Например: 438, 73338, 938472, 32243.

На моем ПК такого не происходит. Причем не при каждой последовательности чисел в массиве, после инициализации, сбиваются данные. В интернете я ничего не смог найти, поэтому единственное решение которое мне помогло - это создать `List<int>`, в него, через `Add`, добавить последовательность, а потом конвертировать в массив, через LINQ.

Второй случай произошёл с переменной типа `Dictionary`, где в качестве ключа выступает `enum`, а в значении хранится делегат. При прямой инициализации, у некоторых пользователей программы падает с ошибкой отсутствия указанного ключа. На моём ПК всё так же работает. Эта последовательность никак не меняется с течением жизни программы. И вот тут я уже не знаю, что можно сделать.

Что такого может стоять у пользователей, что мешает работе программы? Как найти причину этого поведения? И что сделать, чтобы такого избежать?

Была ли у кого-нибудь похожая проблема?

Comment: *Зевая* - Ошибки в вашем коде. Небось, вы инициализируете локальный массив, а в другом месте используете массив-поле класса, который неинициализирован. Но так как вы не показываете свой код, остается лишь гадать...

Comment: Простите. Для первого примера  достаточного и одной строчки в консольном приложении, с инициализацией этой переменной. Для второго случая чуть позже добавлю пример, но он тоже очень простой. Словарь инициализируется в конструкторе класса и в этом же классе другой метод использует эту переменную.

Comment: _достаточно одной строчки_ - нет, не достаточно, ведь ещё нужно сделать вывод, чтобы посмотреть, что там. В таком [примере](https://ideone.com/wTrdFF) - у вас иногда выводятся другие числа?

Comment: Вы как начинающий, вы ведь сами себя так представили, не можете правильно определить причину возникновения ошибки. Выставляете на показ строку, которая явно не содержит никакой ошибки, но почему-то пытаетесь нас убедить, что вот она, эта строка, во всем виновата, хотя собака порылась где-то в другом месте, которое вы не хотите показать. И чем же вас так `List<int>` не устроил? Если вы гонитесь за оптимизацией кода, то вот этой бесполезной операцией: "...List<int>, в него, через Add, добавить последовательность, а потом конвертировать в массив" вы наоборот все замедляете.

Comment: Ошибки подобного рода в 99.999999999999999% случаях говорят о проблемах в вашем коде. То есть есть где то проблема, которую вы не видите, но она у вас в коде.

Comment: В тегах стоит `ram`. Так-то да, причиной ошибок может быть глючащая память. Но тогда ошибки будут возникать не только с вашим приложением, но и с другими. Что-то такое наблюдается?